# How to autofill textbox from suggestion list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am a beginner in jquery and ajax. I'm trying to get google like suggestion while typing in the textbox. However I've tried for hours and still can't get to view the suggestion as a list and autofill the textbox while selecting text from the list. Here is what I've tried so far.

The php file-

```
    $conn = new mysqli("host", "user",  "pass", "database");
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }       
    $sql = "SELECT data1, data2 FROM table";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    // get the q parameter from URL
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    $hint = "";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
                if ($q !== "") {
                $q = strtolower($q);
                $len=strlen($q);
                    foreach($row as $name) {
                        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
                            if ($hint === "") {
                                $hint = $name;
                            } 
                            else {
                                $hint .= "</br> <a href='#'>$name </a>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }   

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
    echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
```

The Javascript code-

```
    function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
         document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
         document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
        return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getdb.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

The html file-

```
<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<div>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
<div id="livesearch">
</div>
</div>
```

Another problem is the first suggestion from the list isn't appearing as a link like rest of the suggestion.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8REz3.png)

How can I list my suggestions properly and how can I can fill the textbox when a user selects text from the list. Pl's help!

Comment: Why you do `if ($hint === "") { $hint = $name;}`?

Comment: I'm not sure myself. I copied and modified the code from w3schools tutorials. Haven't tested out why it was necessary. Edit- Removing that part seems to have solved the first suggestion not appearing as link problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself few days ago. Here is what the code looks like so far.

The php file-

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    //$hint = "";
    $sql = "SELECT data FROM tables WHERE Firstdata LIKE '%" . $q .  "%' OR Lastdata LIKE '%" . $q ."%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $FirstData  =$row['Firstdata']; 
        $LastData =$row['Lastdata']; 
        $ID=$row['ID']; 

//-display the result of the array
        if ($q !== "") {
            echo "<li class="."list-group-item".">"
                            . "<a  href=\"phpfile.php?id=$ID\">" .
                            $FirstData ." ". $LastData . "</a>
                            </li>";
        }
    }
```

The Javascript code-

```
        function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
         document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
         document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
        return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px solid";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","php/ajaxphpfile.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

The html file-

```
     <input type="text" class="search-query form-control" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" id="type" name="name"placeholder="Search" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="oldsearch" class="btn btn-danger" type="button"></button>
<div id="livesearch"></div>
```